# Cannot play downloaded Amazon Prime videos offline when saved to SD card

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

from my galaxy tab s3, I can download and play videos offline with the Amazon Prime app if I save them to my internal storage.  However, if I save them to my sandisk mirco sdCard (200gb), the downloads seems to complete successfully, but I cannot play the videos.  The same offline watching works fine with Netflix.

Is this a known limitation of Prime, or is there some way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like its an sd card issue, since I tried reformatting it both in my GalaxyTabS3 and on my fedora machine, and i get errors.  false alarm...

Answer (score 0):

a while ago GOOGLE and the ANDROID team had made it so that certain things cannot be accessed or written to the SD card due to exploits. it has been this way since 4.1 i think?

Unless there's an option to specify the SD card with the application, i doubt it

You did save the files using the application correct? or did ya move them from the Internal to the external? if you did this then that might be the issue. you will have to put the save path as the SD card if it allows it. if not, then blame google for screwing with how Android devices read/write permissions with the SD card.

also this really isnt the place to ask these question, you SHOULD contact AMAZON customer support....

Comment: i have contacted amazon support, and I'm awaiting a reply.  As for the app settings, i used the Prime app to set where to save the files.  i've looked around on both the sd card and internal, but cant seem to find where the videos are saved, since the "com.amazon.thirdparty..." dir is empty in both, yet, the file still shows as present in Prime and plays when saved to internal storage.

Comment: well then thats the problem. id suggest waiting on amazon to help yoou with it. have you tried manually moving the files to the Com.Amazon.thirdparty... directory on the SD Card?